# apiVersion and beta versions

Tags: kubernetes

Following the docs to create a Deployment, I have a .yaml file like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
```

I wasn't sure what to make of the "extensions/v1beta1", so I ended up [here in the API docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api/#v1beta1-v1beta2-and-v1beta3-are-deprecated-please-move-to-v1-asap).

That makes it sound like I should use a value of "v1", but that doesn't seem to be valid when I try to `kubectl apply` my .yaml file.

Could someome help me to better understand what the ***apiVersion*** values mean and how I can determine the best value to use for each component?

Oh, and I'm using minikube and "kubectl version" reports that client and server are "GitVersion:"v1.3.0".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The docs you linked to are from before the release of Kubernetes 1.0 (a year ago). At that time, we had beta versions of the API and were migrating to the v1 API. Since then, we have introduced multiple API groups, and each API group can have a different version. The version indicates the maturity of the API (alpha is under active development, beta means it will have compatibility/upgradability guarantees, and v1 means it's stable). The deployment API is currently in the second category, so using `extensions/v1beta1` is correct.

Comment: Robert - Thanks.  I cannot find a list of available versions that can be used in the `apiVersion` field.  Is there a list of possible versions?  For example, I gather that as of the day I write this comment, the most recent stable version is `api/v1` - but I can't find that confirmed anywhere in the k8s documentation.  Is there a link to a page with the list of API versions and the corresponding string to use in the `apiVersion` field, including the most recent stable version?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum here is what I discovered. The swagger API spec is located in /swaggerapi. I can see what versions are supported. Example: `{ "path": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1", "description": "API at /apis/extensions/v1beta1"}`

Comment: @Robert Baily is there a table that will tell me which set of API versions I should be using, given a k8s cluster version? K8s always assume I always have a nice, up-to-date cluster (1.12 at time of writing) but platform providers don't always live on this bleeding edge so it can get frustrating quite quickly

Comment: Not that I know of (you can maybe figure it out scouring the release notes, but that doesn't sound automatable). It would be worth submitting a feature request via GitHub to ask for a data source to query this from (even if it's just a file inside the release).

Comment: Shout out to Matthew Palmer for [this helpful table](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-apiversion-definition-guide.html) of apiVersions and kinds.

Answer (score 1):

[from documentation suggested by @Vern DeHaven](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-apiversion-definition-guide.html)

**extensions/v1beta1**

This version of the API includes many new, commonly used features of Kubernetes. Deployments, DaemonSets, ReplicaSets, and Ingresses all received significant changes in this release.

Note that in Kubernetes 1.6, some of these objects were relocated from extensions to specific API groups (e.g. apps). When these objects move out of beta, expect them to be in a specific API group like `apps/v1`.

**Using `extensions/v1beta1` is becoming deprecated—try to use the specific API group where possible, depending on your Kubernetes cluster version.**

Comment: Script to find outdated api versions in a cluster: https://github.com/dguyhasnoname/k8s-day2-ops/blob/master/upgrade/k8s-deprecations.sh